# Breakdown discount at checkout cart and order summary

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, shopping-cart-price-rules, checkout-page

I have 2 applied discount, but at checkout cart and order summary it only shows one discount name with the total of the discount

[image]

[image]

How can I breakdown the discount, so it will show each discount name and total?